# What data type can be used to hold the value of the factorial of 100,000,000?

Tags: java, types, numbers

Data type to hold a very large number say 1000 or more digits?
I need to find the factorial of a large number say 100000000.
My factorial program works nice for a smaller number.

```
long factorial(int x)
{
    long fact=1;
    if(x<0)
            {
        System.out.println("Incorrect input, enter a positive number");
        fact=0;
    }
    if(x==0)
        fact=1;
    if(x>0)
            {
            fact=x;
        fact=fact*factorial(x-1);

    }
    return fact;
}
```

Comment: The Universe? No, way too small.

Comment: Use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: Well, what makes you calculate the factorial of such a gigantic number?

Comment: i just want to try it , beyond our usual limit..

Comment: The difference between the largest factorial you can store in a `long` and the largest one you can store in *the whole computer* is disappointingly small :)

Comment: Don't forget to post the result.

Answer (score 7):

You need a `BigInteger`. It can hold an arbitrarily large number.

But in your case `100000000!` is such a huge number, that nothing can help.

Comment: It can't :) It just doesn't have a predefined limit. It can't hold OP's number.

Comment: Yes, but it his only choice for a number larger than `Long`.

Comment: It's his best bet, that's true. But if he is interested in the factorial of *a hundred million*, all the elementary particles of all the Universe will not help him.

Comment: Not even sure it's his best bet.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik. Elementary Particle. mhmm.. Reminded me of my Chemistry class. Hated that subject like HELL.

Comment: I doubt that this is about chemistry or elementary particles.  It's just bad programming.

Comment: @RohitJain In Chemistry they mention only three out of many dozens of elementary particles :) It's more the stuff of Physics.

Comment: What is your estimate of the number of digits in the result?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik. Yeah. But something that have tortured you so much  comes to your mind first. ;)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Wolfram Alpha gave me the approximation of 80,000,000! and it's 10^10^8.7. That's a number with almost a billion digits.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Any reason BigInteger on a 64 bit computer with a few gigabytes of memory could not store a billion digit number?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan No, that's actually the point of my above comment. Maybe it wasn't explicit enough. Too bad it would take a lifetime to compute it with OP's code, though :)

Answer (score 5):

You should use a log of gamma function, since `gamma(n) = (n-1)!`  Far more efficient than your *naive*, student way of doing things.  It'll be a double in that case, and the natural log will grow more slowly than the value does.

Recursion?  *Please*.  Your problem won't be the size of the value you pass back - you'll get too many stack frames and out of memory error long before that.

Comment: i have recently started doing things in java..
will take some to get lift my level ..
Thanks a lot :)
for giving me another way to try

Comment: gamma won't be recursive, so that problem goes away.  It'll return a double, so you'll be able to return a number up to Double.MAX_VALUE in size.  Two problems solved, plus it's far more efficient.

Comment: could you please write the snippet .. i am a bit stuck how to start :(

Comment: Why write it?  Just use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Gamma.html

Answer (score 1):

While `BigInteger` will theoretically handle such a value, you won't be able to compute it in practise.

First, your algorithm uses recursion, so you'd need 100.000.000 recursive calls of `factorial`. You'll get stack overflow far before computing the result. You'd have to modify your algorithm to avoid recursion (use a loop for example).

Second, the result will be **huge**. Using [formulas for approximating factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n) such as

```
log n! ~~ n log(n/e)
```

we can conclude that your number will have more than 750.000.000 digits. While with some luck you might be able to fit it into your memory, you will certainly not be able to compute the number in any reasonable time. Just imagine - you'll have to perform 100.000.000 multiplications with numbers that have hundreds of millions of digits.